# How to create an excel sheet with text format?

Tags: java, excel

I am using SXSSFWorkbook for creating excel file. I know how to create data format for excel cell like this:

```
DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
        CellStyle cellStyleText = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyleText.setDataFormat(
                fmt.getFormat("@"));
```

But this one is good when you are trying to write the datas into the cell and at the same time indicate its format. But I want to set ALL cells in excel to text format, NOT only the cells I am  writing datas into. In default it creates sheet with general cell format. So I would like to know is there any tips for setting this cells into text format?

Comment: You might as well write csv - why don't you?

Comment: @g00se It is a project obligation, so not csv

Comment: ["*You can provide a template workbook which is used as basis for the written data*"](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) - so maybe that "template" can be composed of the plain style?

Comment: So I need a template with already text format indicated for cells? Did I get it right?

Comment: That is my reading. I could be wrong so seek confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, having all cells using text data format in a spreadsheet is not really a good idea. In such a sheet no formulas will work. This contradicts the main usage of spreadsheets.

But your question is mainly about how to set a special default cell style for each cell in the sheet. In your case the special text style but that also could be any other style.

One solution would be using a template which already has that special style set for all cells. Then one could do something like this:

```
...
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./template.xlsx"));
SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook((XSSFWorkbook)workbook); 
Sheet sxssfSheet = sxssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
// stream in the data into the sheet
...
```

If you need doing this from scratch, then one could start having a new `XSSFWorkbook`. Then create the needed cell style and apply this for all cells.

The class [ColumnHelper](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/helpers/ColumnHelper.html) provides methods to set a default style to all cells in one given column. But it lacks methods to do this for all columns. So `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper` needs to be extended to provide that functionality.

Following complete example shows this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyle {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();    
  DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  textStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));  
   
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  MyColumnHelper columnHelper = new MyColumnHelper(((XSSFSheet)sheet).getCTWorksheet());
  columnHelper.setColDefaultStyle(0, workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastColumnIndex(), textStyle);
     
  SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook((XSSFWorkbook)workbook); 
  Sheet sxssfSheet = sxssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
  // stream in the data into the sheet
   
  FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
  sxssfWorkbook.write(fileout);
  fileout.close();
  sxssfWorkbook.close();
  sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
 }
}

class MyColumnHelper extends org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper {
    
 public MyColumnHelper(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet worksheet) {
  super(worksheet);
 }
 
 public void setColDefaultStyle(long fromCol, long toCol, CellStyle style) {
  setColDefaultStyle(fromCol, toCol, style.getIndex());
 }  
 public void setColDefaultStyle(long fromCol, long toCol, int styleId) {
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCol col = getOrCreateColumn1Based(fromCol+1, true);
  col.setMax(toCol+1);
  col.setStyle(styleId);
 } 
}
```

After running this code `Excel.xls` contains one sheet having all cells using the cell style where data format "Text" is set. It is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2`.

Comment: Is it also appliable with SXSSFWorkbook and SXSSFSheet?

Comment: @Alex: Not clear what your question is about. The code *is* using `SXSSFWorkbook ` and `SXSSFSheet`.

Comment: You are creating sheet with "Sheet". I am creating with "SXSSFSheet". And when I am casting my sheet to (XSSFSheet), it doesnt let me do this.

Comment: @Alex: `Sheet` is an interface which is implemented by all sheet classes, also by `XSSFSheet` and `SXSSFSheet`. But yes, one cannot cast `SXSSFSheet` to `XSSFSheet`. And `SXSSFSheet` does not provide methods to get `CTWorksheet`, which is needed to apply the default column style. But each `SXSSFWorkbook` has a underlying `XSSFWorkbook`. So creating `SXSSFWorkbook` from `XSSFWorkbook` is good practice.

Comment: Here how I create it: InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("template.xlsx"); SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream));  Maybe the problem is that I am using stream (cast problem)?

Comment: @Alex: But then why not `XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);` ... set the default column style in `xssfWorkbook` ... `SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssfWorkbook); ...`? Or just applying the text data format to be the default cell style in the Excel template file read using `inputStream`? Just select all cells in all sheets in that template in Excel GUI and format as "Text".